# Clean Up This Webscrape

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code gets into a webpage and bypasses the login

(I have set up my sample account in the code so it will run fine when you run it)

Once I get to the desired page, I want to scrape all the titles/time of each row.

My code currently only scrapes the first row - You can see this if you run it. But I want all the rows.

Namely, if you look at the rows that have arrows on the top right, they have a drop down which list more rows. These are mainly what I want to scrape as there are much more of these and automating this would be really helpful.

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://sobp.societyconference.com/conf/#sessions/conf10007')
time.sleep(4)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

#Just Navigation
userid=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txt-home-login-email"]')
userid.send_keys('kbradons04@gmail.com')
password=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txt-home-login-password"]')
password.send_keys('Test123')
submit=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-home-login"]')
submit.click()
time.sleep(2)
button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-confirm-address"]')
button.click()
button1=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-navigation"]/div[3]')
button1.click()
time.sleep(10)


page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
productlist=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="list-agenda"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]').text
print(productlist)
```

Comment: i tried this and it does not work. If you can try and post your solution I can take a look

Comment: Did you want the description as well?

Comment: No, it is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
products = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='ip-agenda-session']")

for product in products:
    print(product.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='ip-session-name']").text)
    print(product.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='ip-session-room']").text)
    
    try:
        elem = product.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@data-original-title='Show Session Details']")
        elem.click()
        innerproducts=product.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='ip-as-abstract-conatiner']/div")
        for inner in innerproducts:
            print(inner.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='ip-as-title']").text)
            print(inner.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='ip-as-second-cat']").text)
            
    except Exception as e:
        #print(str(e))
        pass
```

So you want to grab all 40 or so elements by their name and time.

```
Virtual Help Desk
Wed 4 PM - 9 PM
Predoctoral Scholars Orientations (Invitation Only)
Wed 4:30 PM - 5 PM
```

Comment: Thanks Arun but if you look at my screenshot in the picture, or if you check the second row under Thursday, April 29, there are arrows on the top right corner that if you click on this, it expands and more sessions will be shown. Those are the main ones that i want. Example the title - "The Human in Humanity"

Comment: So you want to click all of them and get just those values? Or do you want them as well  with the others.

Comment: as well with others would be ideal, but click on them would work too. either is fine to be honest

Comment: Try something like this. I might want to check if they have an api or something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `find_elements_by_xpath` instead of `find_element_by_xpath`. The former will return a list of item.

Source:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: i tried this and it does not work. If you can try and post your solution I can take a look